# send keyCode without key event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, adobe

I got this function (in the document class)

```
public function kyz(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        trace(event.keyCode);
        switch (event.keyCode){
            case 65:{
                if (ppm.currentFrame<200 || ppm.currentFrame>300) {
                    ppm.gotoAndStop(301);
                    ssm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    llm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    mmm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    myTimer.stop();
                    pd.play();
                }else {
                    pd.play();
                    ppm.gotoAndPlay(10);
                    tlrnc-=10;
                }               
                break;
            }
            case 68:{
                if (ssm.currentFrame<200 || ssm.currentFrame>300) {
                    ssm.gotoAndStop(301);
                    ppm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    llm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    mmm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    myTimer.stop();
                    mTimer.stop();
                    sd.play();
                }else {
                    sd.play();
                    ssm.gotoAndPlay(10);
                    tlrnc-=10;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 74:{
                if (llm.currentFrame<200 || llm.currentFrame>300) {
                    llm.gotoAndStop(301);
                    ppm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    ssm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    mmm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    myTimer.stop();
                    mTimer.stop();
                    ld.play();
                }else {
                    ld.play();
                    llm.gotoAndPlay(10);
                    tlrnc-=10;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 76:{
                if (mmm.currentFrame<200 || mmm.currentFrame>300) {
                    mmm.gotoAndStop(301);
                    ppm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    ssm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    llm.gotoAndStop(302);
                    myTimer.stop();
                    mTimer.stop();
                    md.play();
                }else {
                    md.play();
                    mmm.gotoAndPlay(10);
                    tlrnc-=10;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

that receives key event's and do stuff. now I'm trying to pass they keyCode from another function (to avoid changing the whole code for adding click functionality) got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could dispatch a `KeyboardEvent`

```
stage.dispatchEvent(
  new KeyboardEvent(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, true, false, myCharCode, myKeyCode));
```

just add the needed keyCode as a parameter

Comment: Looks like the easy way I was looking for is actually more code than I expected ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send any Keyboard or Mouse event without interactivity with user. You can handle this in another private function:

```
    private function keyDownHandler(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
        this.handleEvent(event.keyCode);
    }

    private function handleEvent(keyCode : uint) : void {
        //some actions
    }
```

And when you need to make specific actions, you can just call `handleEvent` function without user side interactivity.

Comment: this is not true, you can fake user activity

Comment: I did something like this and I just wanted to see if there is any other way ^_^